# React Redux + Saga Image Carousel

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-saga

I'm building a carousel which contains a main image and a list of thumbnail images.

[image]

There are prev and next buttons to allow the user to navigate through the list of images.

Here is my code so far:

```
import styles from './carousel.css';
import cn from '../../../utils/classname';
import actions from '../../../actions';

import Magnified from '../../../svg/icons/ui/magnified_glass';
import ArrowRight from '../../../svg/icons/ui/arrow_right';
import ArrowLeft from '../../../svg/icons/ui/arrow_left';

const Carousel = ({ dispatch, selectedCaravan }) =>
  <div className={cn(styles.carouselWrap)}>
        <div className={cn(styles.carouselFeatWrap)}>
            <a href="#" className={cn(styles.carouselExpand)} onClick={() => dispatch({ type: actions.CAROUSEL_EXPAND })}>
                <Magnified />
            </a>
            <ul className={cn(styles.carousel)}>
        {selectedCaravan.images && selectedCaravan.images.map((image, i) => {
          return <li key={i}>
            <img src={image} />
          </li>;
        })}
            </ul>   
        </div>
        <div className={cn(styles.carouselThumbNavWrap)}>
            <ul className={cn(styles.carouselThumbnails)}>
        {selectedCaravan.images && selectedCaravan.images.map((image, i) => {
          return <li key={i} onClick={() => dispatch ({ type: actions.CAROUSE_GO_TO })}>
            <img src={image} />
          </li>;
        })}
            </ul>
            <div className={cn(styles.carouselNavigation)}>
                <a href="#" className={cn(styles.carouselNavPrev)} onClick={() => dispatch({ type: actions.CAROUSEL_PREV })}>
                    <ArrowLeft />
                </a>
                <a href="#" className={cn(styles.carouselNavNext)} onClick={() => dispatch({ type: actions.CAROUSEL_NEXT })}>
                    <ArrowRight />
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
  </div>;

export default Carousel;
```

I have actions such as `CAROUSEL_NEXT` and `CAROUSEL_PREV`. I am listening for these actions within my sagas and my thinking on this is I need to update the selected index and somehow update the main image to whichever the user has selected.

My saga looks like this so far:

```
const carouselPrev = function* (payload) {

  const updateSelectedIndex = payload.updateSelectedIndex;

  if (updateSelectedIndex) {
    return false;
  }

  yield put({ type: actions.CAROUSEL_PREV, payload: updateSelectedIndex });

};
```

I'm unsure how to update the selected index when a user selects a new image and how to animate or essentially make the carousel slide.

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't need the saga at all.

You just define the actions for the reducer

```js
// Action creators
const selectNext = () => ({
  type: 'SELECT_NEXT',
})

const selectPrev = () => ({
  type: 'SELECT_PREV',
})

const selectById = (id) => ({
  type: 'SELECT_BY_ID',
  payload: id,
})

// Reducer

const initial = {
  selectedImageId: 0,
  /* other state */
}

function reducer(state = initial, action) {
  switch(action.type) {
    case 'SELECT_NEXT':
      return {
        ...state,
        selectedImageId: state.selectedImageId + 1,
      }
    case 'SELECT_PREV':
      return {
        ...state,
        selectedImageId: state.selectedImageId - 1,
      }
    case 'SELECT_BY_ID':
      return {
        ...state,
        selectedImageId: action.payload,
      }
    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

after this you pass the callbacks from `react-redux`

```js
const Component = ({ selectedImageId, onNext, onPrev, onSelect }) => (
  <div>
    <CarouselMainImage 
      id={selectedImageId} // this component will know which image to display based on this id
    />
    {/* ... */}
    <CarouselImages
      onClick={onSelect}
    />
    {/* ... */}
    <PrevBtn
      onClick={onPrev}
    />
    <NextBtn
      onClick={onNext}
    />
    {/* ... */}
  </div>
)

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  selectedImageId: state.selectedImageId
})

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch =>
  // use action creators here
  bindActionCreators({
    onNext: onSelectNext,
    onPrev: onSelectPrev,
    onSelect: onSelectById,
  }, dispatch)

const ConnectedComponent = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)
```

For transitions, you could use this: https://github.com/reactjs/react-transition-group

Comment: Thank you for this @notgiorgi. I'm wondering with the first snippet of code where do those action creators go as I already have actions set up listening for the on click?

Comment: Action creators are just helpers to easily dispatch the actions, instead of writing them by hand every time

Comment: Ok thanks, I'm just trying to figure out how I can apply this to my project and  which code goes where if that makes sense.

Comment: To help this the project is using Ramda and incrementing state like the above

Comment: Well, if you're talking file-system-wise, you should have: `actions.js` for action creators, `reducer.js` for reducer and `constants.js` for action types (it's not a good practice to pass strings around). You might also have `selectors.js` and move `state.selectedImageId` there

Comment: also take a look at recommendations in official docs: http://redux.js.org/docs/faq/CodeStructure.html